# How do I allocate memory for an array of structs of arbitrary length and point to it?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

```
struct foo{
member
member
}array[]

struct bar{
member
member
struct foo* p
}

array = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct foo))
p = &array[0]
```

I want to mallocate memory for an arbitrary number which the struct foo array shall hold. How do I do that?
I also want struct foo* p to point at the struct foo array.
I do something wrong with this but I don't know how to think about this.

If I cannot mallocate an array of structs this way how should I do it then?

Comment: The bit where you allocate memory is fine, but the rest of it is where you're having trouble. An array of unknown length (`array[]`) is not the same as a pointer (what `malloc` returns), and you can't access `p` without a `bar` object.

Comment: This *must* be a duplicate.

Comment: You mention `struct bar` in your code, but not in your question. Why?

Comment: You seem to have an aversion to semicolons.  The C compiler will have an aversion to you omitting semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a running example of what you want to achieve - you can play around with it on [ideone](https://ideone.com/l9El7w)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
 int haz;
 int cheez;
} foo;

typedef struct {
 foo* p;
} bar;

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    bar mybar;
    bar *mybar_ptr;

    foo* myfoo_array  = malloc(10*sizeof *myfoo_array);

    if(myfoo_array == NULL) {
      puts("ERROR: Could not allocate memory");
      return 1;
    }       

    myfoo_array[5].haz   = 1337;
    myfoo_array[5].cheez = 42;

    mybar.p   = myfoo_array;
    //  assigns the address of mybar to the mybar_ptr 
    mybar_ptr = &mybar;

    printf("haz: %d, cheez: %d\n", mybar.p[5].haz, mybar.p[5].cheez);

    // access as pointer
    printf("haz: %d, cheez: %d\n", mybar_ptr->p[5].haz, mybar_ptr->p[5].cheez);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This: `foo* myfoo_array = malloc(10*sizeof *myfoo_array);` is a bit more robust, since you don't have to repeat the name of the element type. (As the code is modified, it's too easy to change one reference without changing the other.) And you should *definitely* test whether `myfoo_array == NULL` before trying to dereference it.

Comment: Why do you do mybar.p = myfoo_array; and not mybar->p = myfoo_array;?

Comment: since `mybar` is not a pointer in my example, I added an example with a pointer to `mybar` for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to make an array that contains elements of type `foo`.  The following code does that:

```
    (001)    int   number = 10, ndx;
    (002)
    (003)    typedef struct _foo
    (004)    {
    (005)        int member1;
    (006)        int member2;
    (007)    } foo, *pfoo;
    (008)
    (009)    pfoo ptr = malloc(number * sizeof(foo));
```

So what is going on here.  The flines 3 through 7 defines your new type (the structure, I've just included two integers to make it concrete).  In addition, the typedef (remember the syntax of a typedef is `typedef old_type_name type_alias`) part adds two alias for you structure.

```
 foo is equivalent to struct _foo 
 pfoo is equivalent to struct _foo*
```

Line 9 now allocates a block of memory on the heap large enough to hold `number` copies of `struct _foo (or foo for short)`.

So how would you use this in code.  The following piece of code stores the array index in the first member and the square of the index in the second member.

```
   (010)    for(ndx = 0; ndx < number; ndx++)
   (011)    {
   (012)         ptr[ndx].member1 = ndx;
   (013)         ptr[ndx].member2 = ndx*ndx;
   (014)    }
```

So, this can be a little esoteric to understand, so here are the important
points to remember;

1. ptr is a pointer to a block of memory large enough to hold `number` elements of type foo.
2. the array index notation, *i.e. ptr[]*, is really syntactic-sugar for pointer arithmetic.  For example `ptr[3]` is equivalent to `ptr + 3*sizeof(foo)`.  In other words, we are able to move from sub-block to sub-block in that large chuck of memory that we created in point 1.
3. The arithmetic in point 2 produces an anonymous temporary variable that references a particular sub-block (which we know is a structure). Because we told the compiler that each block would be a structure, we are able to use the member reference (.) to get at the individual field.

So, putting this all together in a short program yields:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct _foo
    {
        int member1;
        int member2;
    } foo, *pfoo;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        int   number = 10, ndx;

        pfoo ptr = malloc(number * sizeof(foo));
        for(ndx = 0; ndx < number; ndx++)
        {
            ptr[ndx].member1 = ndx;
            ptr[ndx].member2 = ndx*ndx;
        }

        for(ndx = 0; ndx < number; ndx++)
        {
            foo     temp = ptr[ndx];
            printf("%d\t%d\n", temp.member1, temp.member2);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

On my system (Ubuntu Linux, this compiles cleanly with a command line of:
`gcc -ansi -Wall -pedanic temp.c -o temp`

---

[edit] - forgot to answer second part of question.

With the above, the answer to your second question should be fairly obvious now (I hope).

Ok, so the two structures you want to use are now:

```
    typedef struct _foo
    {
        int member1;
        int member2;
    } foo, *pfoo;

    typedef struct _bar
    {
        int  member1;
        int  member2;
        pfoo p;     /* or alternatively, struct _foo* p    */
                    /* or alternatively, foo* p            */
    } bar, *pbar;
```

At this point, in your code you can write:

```
    bar      temp;

    temp.member1 = 5;
    temp.member2 = 10;
    temp.p = malloc(number*sizeof(foo));
```

hope this helps,
T.

Comment: Typedefs for pointer types are usually a bad idea; use `*` explicitly. Identifiers starting with `_` are reserved; you shouldn't define them in your own code. Typedefs for structs aren't really necessary; you can refer to the type as `struct foo` or `struct bar` (though a lot of programmers do consider it worthwhile to have a one-word name for the type). My suggestion: `struct foo { /* ... */ }; struct foo *ptr = malloc(count * sizeof *ptr); if (ptr == NULL) /* error handling */`

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of pointer typedefs -- it makes the code difficult to read. The stars need to be visible as pointers have different semantics to non-pointers.

Comment: IMHO, I disagree.  I've been doing typedefs on structs since early 80's and never had a problem.  I feel it makes code easier to read, and certainly easier to type.  Granted your mileage may vary, it really is a personal preference (much like where curly-braces go or the number of spaces in an indent).